# Can ZFS and BtrFS handle files larger than physical discs?

Tags: iso-image, storage, zfs, btrfs, zfsonlinux

Are ZFS and BtrFS able to handle files that are larger than one physical disk so that such a huge file spans over multiple physical discs?

I consider lifting up my file server to a VM. Currently the file archive is stored on simple ext4 partitions and could be moved into ISO files for more flexibility. At some point the ISO files might grows bigger than a single physical disc.